# How to port forward a D-Link DSL-2740U modem?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, modem

I am setting up a modem for port forwarding to a static address by the 9010 port shown in the image below:

[image]

This modem is connected to the PC via an Ethernet cable directly.
I set the local IP address and static IP address to 192.168.1.2 but after checking on [this site](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/). It is closed.

What is the problem?

Comment: Is the firewall setup on the device you are port forwarding to?

Comment: I do not know. How can i check it

Comment: You can most likely find a guide on somewhere. Am I correct in assuming the device is running windows and there is no firewall between the router and device?

Comment: My windows is win server 2012

Comment: This modem connected to PC via Ethernet cable directly

Comment: I'm assuming you understand the risks involved with port forwarding, If not I highly recommend that you do some research before proceeding.

Comment: @Pancakedinner Port redirects are required for a myriad of things _(SSH, VPNs, WAN facing mail servers, WAN facing web servers, etc.)_ and is secure provided it's configured correctly _(UPnP, on the other hand, isn't remotely secure in any form)_

Comment: @hmahdavi Terminology in this instance matters - You're configuring a router, not a modem... You have a modem+router combo and what you're configuring is the router portion.  Modems and routers speak two entirely different languages, one cannot operate as the other, and modems are generally only configurable by the ISP.

Comment: My means of modem is router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port forwarding rule looks good, Except WAN IP Address is set to a specific Interface, In your case you want that set to "Any"

After setting up a port forwarding rule in your router you now must setup the firewall on you device to accept traffic from that port.

**Windows Firewall**

- Open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
- Select Inbound Rules (Top Left)
- Click "New Rule..." (Top Right under actions)
- Select Port
- Everything from here is straight forward

---

portforward.com has guides on how to setup port forwarding on lots of routers.

Your Router: https://portforward.com/d-link/dsl-2740u/me-1-02/

Comment: I do this but dont work !!!

Comment: How are you testing? Is the program/service hosting on that ip/port?

Comment: I upload a website on iis and bind it to 9010 port . I check it by browse "ip static:9010". In local website load currently

Comment: The "ipstatic:9010" I'm guessing this is the local address? (192.168.x.x) If you can't access the website from the server itself then you configured something wrong. try localhost:9010 from the server

Comment: Website load in localhost:9010 currently!!!!

Comment: What if you try the private ip address of the server from another pc on the network?

Comment: No . Ip static is public !!! I try ipstatic:9010

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107105/discussion-between-pancakedinner-and-hmahdavi).

Comment: I define inbound rule for 9010 port in firewall and then change "Wan Interface" to any and website loaded currently -:) . Please add "Wan Interface" changes to your answer.